# Gulp concat jQuery throws error

Tags: gulp, gulp-concat

I'm pretty new to gulp. I'm trying to merge few JS files together and when I add jQuery (or jQuery UI) compiler throws error:

```
events.js:160
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^
Error: [path]\public\components\jquery\dist\jquery.js:16:2: missing '}'
```

My jQuery is fresh copy via bower (version 3.2.1) as is jQuery UI (1.12.1).

My gulp task is following:

```
gulp.task('js', function() {
    gulp.src(
        [
            config.bowerDir + '/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
            config.bowerDir + '/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js',
            './public/js/custom.js'
        ]
    )
        .pipe(concat('script.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/js/'));
} );
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry all, problem was in my own stupidity. My *concat* function was actually *gulp-concat-css* and not *gulp-concat*. Took me three days to spot the error.

```
(...)
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
(...)

gulp.task('js', function() {
    return gulp.src([
            config.bowerDir + '/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
            config.bowerDir + '/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js',
            './public/js/custom.js'
        ])
        .pipe(concat('scripts.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/js/'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
gulp.task('js', function() {
  return gulp.src([
        config.bowerDir + '/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
        config.bowerDir + '/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js',
        './public/js/custom.js'
    ])
    .pipe(concat('script.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/js/'));
});
```

Comment: Sorry, this isn't the right answer. Still getting the same error.

Comment: I posted it above. "  ...\jquery.js:16:2: missing '}'  ". It looks like gulp thinks there's a syntax error in jQuery. I just found out that it does this with any JS file I try except blank ones.

Comment: Perhaps the } was missing at one time, and even though you fixed it, jquery  is still serving the old file.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make myself clear, however I didn't fix anything. Problem is still there. Only thing I said was that I realised that the problems with missing "}", or missing "," or some other problem were in all files I tried (all valid JS files). Only time gulp didn't report the problem was when I tried to merge a blank JS file, otherwise it always fails on some 'missing [symbol]' error.